# Вопрос по разметки boostrap

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap, flexbox, css-grid

Всем привет. Начал изучать boostrap, но столкнулся со сложностью разметки. Нужна разметка по изображению ниже. Сколько не искал по документации, подобного примера я так и не нашел (возможно плохо искал).[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
[class^=col] {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3 blue"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 order-0 red"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 order-2 order-xl-1 green"></div>
        <div class="col-12 order-1 order-xl-2 yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD** Ширина синего блока фиксированная при >= 1200px

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xl.blue {
    flex-basis: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
}

[class^=col] {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl blue"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 order-0 red"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 order-2 order-xl-1 green"></div>
        <div class="col-12 order-1 order-xl-2 yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но остался вопрос по первому столбцу (синего цвета). Например мне нужно чтобы он был шириной 100px, так как у меня в этом блоке находится аватар пользователя. Как я понял, это лучше сделать через media и после media-body создавать разметку колонками, но тогда остается вопрос, как мне растянуть синий блок на 100% при ширине меньше 1200px без костылей из стилей? Или есть другой вариант для этой реализации?

Comment: @hard990, варианты есть разные. Например,  вместо класса `col-xl-3` пишите `col-xl` и добавляете CSS: 
`@media (min-width: 1200px) {.col-xl.blue {flex-basis: 100px;flex-grow: 0;}}`

Comment: @hard990, дополнил в ответе

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос, а как мне быть, если мне нужно, чтобы зелёный блок был по ширине содержимого, а красный был на всю ширину свободного места? Решил сделать флексами, но понял что я тогда не смогу перенести желтый блок. А если обернуть в новый флексбокс не смогу перенести его после красного. Нашел вариант с гридами, но пока не хочется их задействовать, т.к их нет в самом фреймворке. Хочется все сделать средствами boostrap.